# Cannot acces scannotation-1.0.3 jar from CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

Since several days it seems ClouBees cannot access the jar for scannotation-1.0.3.

We have a module that uses Resteasy and Resteasy requires it.
Our POM has a reference to the JBOss repo where things look ok:

```
<repositories>
<!-- For resteasy -->
 <repository>
  <id>jboss</id>
  <name>jboss repo</name>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/scannotation/scannotation/1.0.3/

We've tried the build locally and the jar is fetched without problem.

So, what is preventing CloudBees to get the jar properly?
Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-yves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "jboss" repository ID is automatically mirrored on a local nexus instance to reduce download delays, but mirrors http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/releases
and scannotations 1.0.3 is in jboss "third party releases"

Simple workaround is to change the repository ID